# How to define a structured data type for numpy loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to read a data file which each columns is separated by a tab character and each of the rows looks like this:

```
[475.407, 792.916]  [893.258, 614.066]  [461.864, 356.715]  [758.244, 274.128]
```

Currently, I use numpy.loadtxt to read this file as string and it works fine:

```
data = np.loadtxt (filename, dtype=np.str, delimiter="\t")
```

However what I need is floating point numbers not strings. My expected output is:

```
(np.float32, np.float32) (np.float32, np.float32) (np.float32, np.float32) (np.float32, np.float32)
```

So I decided to define a new data type as np.dtype("f4, f4") so that each element is considered as two floats:

```
data = np.loadtxt (filename, dtype=np.dtype("f4, f4"), delimiter="\t")
```

which leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[475.407, 792.916]'
```

**Question**

- How can I define a new data type for numpy.loadtxt?
- Is there any other alternative with other tools?

Comment: You are simply using the wrong tool here. The data type you seem to want is actually just `np.float64`. But that won't help you, becaue `numpy.readtext` is simply a pretty dumb convenience method for loading simple, character delimited strings.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you suggest other tools like genfromtext?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I updated the question. I would like to read each element [x, y] as floating point numbers not strings.

Comment: @Ali No, since that is essentially equivalent. I would *suggest* fixing the problem at the source: whatever is generating this text, don't do that, and use a pre-built serialization format. Otherwise, I suggest just manually parsing, you can "cheat" and use `ast.literal_eval`. But really, you should just fix the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use [np.fromregex](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html#numpy.fromregex):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.fromregex('test.txt', '(\d+.\d+),\s+(\d+.\d+)', dtype=[('u', np.float32), ('v', np.float32)])

print(arr)
```

**Output**

```
[(475.407, 792.916) (893.258, 614.066) (461.864, 356.715)
 (758.244, 274.128)]
```

Although I advise you follow @juanpa.arrivillaga advise and fix this at the source.

Comment: Thanks.  Although it makes a 1D numpy array instead of 2D, it is a good solution.

Comment: @Ali You can reshape the array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Each element save in x:

```
data = np.loadtxt (filename, dtype=np.str, delimiter="\t")

for txt in data:
    x_list = [float(a) for a in txt[1:-1].split(",")]
    x = np.array(x_list)
```